# JSON data loaded from http.get() is undefined in my Angular 2 template

Tags: json, typescript, angular

I'm trying to read a local json file and parse it into a class that i made which have the same properties. When i try to read from the class, it gives me errors saying the class is null or undefined.

I have a file `hall.ts` which looks like this:

```
import {Item} from '../item/item';
export class Hall {
    constructor(public id:number,
                public naam:string,
                public oppervlakte:number,
                public aantalItems:number,
                public itemsMetNodigeActie:number,
                public items:Item[]) {
    }
}
```

It uses `item.ts`:

```
export class Item {
    constructor(public categorie:string,
                public naam:string,
                public productnummer:string,
                public omschrijving:string,
                public laatsteUitgevoerdeActie:Actie,
                public eerstVolgendeActie:Actie) {
    }
}
export class Actie{
    constructor(datum: string,
                type: string,
                omschrijving: string){}
}
```

The json file, `hall1.json`, that i'm trying to read from looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "naam": "hall1",
  "oppervlakte": 100,
  "aantalItems": 3,
  "itemsMetNodigeActie": 3,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "categorie": "machine",
      "productnummer": "ADE124e",
      "omschrijving": "print papieren af",
      "laatsteUitgevoerdeActie": {
        "datum": "2015-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "type": "vervanging",
        "omschrijving": "papier vervangen"
      },
      "eerstVolgendeActie": {
        "datum": "2016-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "type": "vervanging",
        "omschrijving": "inkt vervangen"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using a `hall.service.ts` which tries to read the json file which is locally stored, and returns it in an `Hall` object. This is the methode for doing that:

```
public getHall(): Observable<Hall> {
    return this.http.get('app/hall/hall1.json')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

I use this method in my `hallDetail.component.ts`

```
export class HallDetailComponent implements OnInit{
    public hall: Hall;
    constructor(
        private service: HallService
    ){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.service.getHall().subscribe((hall:Hall) => {
            this.hall = hall;
        })
    }
}
```

So far it doesn't give me any errors, but when i try to read from the `hall` object, it sais that it is undefined

```
@Component({
    template: `
  <div>
    {{hall.naam}}
  </div>
  `
})
```

Error :

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'naam' of undefined in [
    {{hall.naam}}
   in HallDetailComponent@1:7]
```

Comment: did you try logging the result.json() to see if you are actually loading content?

Comment: Check out [Elvis Operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to remember that the `http.get()` call is async.  Your template is trying to process `hall` as an object before it has been resolved by your async http call.

That's why `hall` is undefined and, therefore, you can't access any properties on it (it does not yet exist).

As Eric mentioned in the comment, try something like this for your template:

```
@Component({
    template: `
  <div>
    {{hall?.naam}}  <!-- note the added ? -->
  </div>
  `
})
```

That will make the reference to `naam` on `hall` null safe.

**Update:**

For the sake of completeness, I'll point out that you can actually use *ngIf for this as well, though the null safe check makes for a cleaner looking template.

```
@Component({
    template: `
  <div *ngIf="hall"> <!-- note the added *ngIf -->
    {{hall.naam}}
  </div>
  `
})
```

Comment: Someone mentioned in another comment on SO that you can get better performance with something like `<div *ngIf="thing">{{thing}}</div>`, because it will only render it if that thing is there.

Comment: @josh That wouldn't surprise me. Using ngIf in Angular 1 was much more performant than ngHide and ngShow for similar reasons. But the bindings are much faster, in theory, in ng2, so if you didn't have 100 of these null safe checks in a view it probably wouldn't make an appreciable difference.